# what exactly runs the quarz cron job in spring?

Tags: java, unit-testing, spring, quartz-scheduler

good people. i'm trying to use quartz with spring in a very simple project managed by maven.So in the module in which the mycron job class is i included a java main class to it just to see the job output some text and new date.
here is my spring config:

```
<!--Scheduling-->
<!--Job-->
    <bean id="projUpdater" class="org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.JobDetailBean">
        <property name="jobClass" value="com.myproject.utilscheduling.quartz.ProjUpdaterCronImpl" />
    </bean>
<!---End of Jobs-->
<!--Triggers-->
    <bean id="regularUpdateTrigger" class="org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.CronTriggerBean">
        <property name="jobDetail" ref="projUpdater"/>
        <property name="cronExpression" value="30 1 * * * ?"/>
    </bean>
<!--End ofTriggers-->
<!--Scheduler Factory-->
<bean class="org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.SchedulerFactoryBean">
    <property name="triggers">
        <list>
            <ref bean="regularUpdateTrigger"/>
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>
<!--End of Scheduler Factory-->
<!--End of Scheduling-->
```

and here is the job class

```
public class ProjUpdaterCronImpl extends QuartzJobBean {

public ProjUpdaterCronImpl() {
}


protected void executeInternal (JobExecutionContext ctx) throws JobExecutionException {
    System.out.println("[JOB] " + new Date() + "hello");
}

}
```

here is main class

```
public class NewMain {

/**
 * @param args the command line arguments
 */
 public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println("starting job");
 }

}
```

so in my understanding the job will be started after 1mn30s and posted on the console.I'm wrong.i faced couple or errors that i solve so i can safely assume that there is no error in in spring configuration file since there is none when building and running.So what did i do wrong or what did i forget to do?

second concern since i'm forcing myself to go the test driven way how will i possibly test a the cron job class?
thanks for reading

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your cron expression

```
<property name="cronExpression" value="30 1 * * * ?"/>
```

actually configures the trigger to fire once every hour at 1 minute 30 seconds after the hour.

Zoidberg's suggestion to use [`MethodInvokingJobDetailFactoryBean`](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.5.x/api/org/springframework/scheduling/quartz/MethodInvokingJobDetailFactoryBean.html) allows you to code your cron job as a POJO, making it easy to test.

Comment: No, "0 * * * * ?" fires every minute.  Check out the documentation at 
http://www.opensymphony.com/quartz/wikidocs/CronTriggers%20Tutorial.html

Comment: thanks dude i have to really sit down and read this stuffs thanks man

Answer (score 0):

Try this for your job bean.

```
<bean id="projUpdater" class="org.springframework.scheduling.quartz.MethodInvokingJobDetailFactoryBean">
        <property name="targetObject" ref="registeredObject" />
        <property name="targetMethod" value="methodNameInObject" />
    </bean>
```

Where your registeredObject is a bean registered in the spring config somewhere.  And the method is a method that exists in that object.

Comment: i'll try your suggestion i've been seeing this form on the net a lot .by the way how to get what i did work actually unless i won't know how to use it that way.i mean for a beginner like me it's key to know what i did wrong.thanks